# Are add-ins in compose mode already supported in Outlook Mobile or not?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have found many threads and articles saying compose mode is not available in Outlook add-ins for mobile, however, [this GitHub page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/main/docs/outlook/add-mobile-support.md#code-considerations) doesn't seem to list this under limitations at the bottom. While I haven't found any examples of it working (and haven't been able to make it work myself), I'm wondering what that is about and if anyone knows if it is possible at this time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the following sentence in the [Compose mode and appointments](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/main/docs/outlook/add-mobile-support.md#compose-mode-and-appointments) section:

> Currently, add-ins in Outlook Mobile only support activation when reading messages.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .